# HTML size for retina display

Tags: html, retina

I don't often get to work for high resolution displays as most of my clients tend to work with the oldest machines known to man, however I'm currently working on something which will only be displayed on retina display iPads. A graphic has been mocked up of the design they want to the retina resolution (2,048 by 1,536) and I've been building my site based off the dimensions in the graphic. However now I'm actually trying to view it on an iPad, everything is far too big, my '260px header' which I assumed would take up a 6th of the page (ish) is closer to double that.

I don't seem to be able to find anything regarding a workable HTML size for retina displays, only pages talking about how to prep images for retina, what size resolution should I work to when building the HTML?

Comment: @AndyHolmes but that's what I mean, I'm using the dimensions from the graphic that's been mocked up to the retina resolution, and my header that's 260px tall on my monitor, which is effectively about a 6th of the height of the retina resolution, is much bigger than that.

Comment: So what size is the graphic?

Comment: It's pixel density, not double height as far as I'm aware

Comment: The mock-up is 2048x1536, but I've measured parts of it (eg the header at 260) and made my HTML by css to 260, but in scale when looking at it on an iPad with retina, its much bigger in proportion than the mock-up I'm working from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way for you to achieve this is to use CSS where possible and build your site at `1024x768` utilising `@2x` graphics for retina devices.

A simple guide on utilising these ideas can be found here - http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/2012/creating-retina-images-for-your-website/

Comment: I think this is effectively the answer im looking for, that the resolution is actually 1024x768 but at double density, which means that now I've halved the height of my header, it's effectively the right proportion to my mock-up image

Comment: Excellent, glad it helped :)